# front-end for GAE datastore - phpMyAdmin-like for GAE

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, phpmyadmin, database-administration

is there some front end that could allow an admin to insert, update, delete records, and create modify and drop tables from Google Application Engine datastore, just like you do with phpMyAdmin on mysql???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google App Engine provides out of the box an [administration console](http://code.google.com/intl/it/appengine/docs/adminconsole/) to manage your records.

As a valid alternative, have a look to the [App Engine admin](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-admin/) project.

> **Implemented features**
>
> - List records for each registered model
> - Create new records
> - Update/edit records
> - Delete records
> - Paging of items in Appengine Admin list view

[Here](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-admin/wiki/Features) the complete list of implemented features.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore? It's very basic but it is already there.

Answer (score 1):

In production, the admin console provides this functionality. In the SDK, you can go to `/_ah/admin/datastore` for the same.